# Error Compiling truffle project, stuck with unfound error,

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, windows-subsystem-for-linux, truffle

I am using WSL (ubuntu 18.04) I've installed truffle, solc, and node js (npm)...
I've started a simple project in truffle and then when I compile using `truffle compile`. I stuck with an error

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.compile (/mnt/c/Users/Test/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/legacy/index.js:72:1)
Truffle v5.1.2 (core: 5.1.2)
Node v13.5.0
```

I couldn't even locate this `index.js` file. Where could this be?

Comment: Could you paste your contract code?

Answer (score 0):

Check your contract pragma statement or truffle config.
If you might be compiling against wrong solidity compiler.